# Wordpress not saving changes to code

Tags: html, wordpress

I was given an assignment to add a payfast "pay now" button. I managed to generate a code for the button and it works just fine. I had to integrate the pay now button into the companies website. The button is coded in HTML and the company's website is done in wordpress. so my problem now is that when I add the code to a page in the wordpress site, some lines in the code disappear. I added the code in the text tab and not the visual tab.

Please help! I do not know what the problem is now.

Comment: can you provide the button code?

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding the code into a "rich text editor" like WordPress's main post body field, it will likely edit the code for what it thinks are display purposes.

See if there is a `visual` and `text` tab at the top right of the post editor and drop your code into the `text` tab, instead.

[image: WP Rich Text Editor]

Alternatively, create a shortcode that renders your button's HTML.

```
// functions.php

// ...
add_shortcode('payfast', 'payfast_renderer');

function payfast_renderer() {
    echo '<button class="btn btn--lerato btn--payfast">Pay Here</button>';
}
```

You could then render that HTML by typing [payfast] into the content editor on a post page.

Read the WP Codex entry on shortcodes for a little more background on how shortcodes work! Reliable way to render page content that relies on HTML and even server-side code.

[[WP Codex Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)]